# Transformations and Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

[image: Provlems]

Hi, for these problems I generally get the gist of it. If you have some linearly dependent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then when you transform those vectors $T(v_1), \dots, T(v_m)$ they will still be dependent, no matter what space they are in.

And for the second problem, if $n < p$ and $m < p$ then the $T(v_1), \ldots, T(v_m)$ will have $p-m$ more vectors than a basis in space $P$ and as such may not necessarily be independent.

First, is that correct logic? Second, this might be me overthinking, but what about the scenario where we have $v_1, \ldots, v_n vectors$ that are independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we then then move to $\mathbb{R}^p$. Where $p < n$, $T(v_1), \ldots, T(v_n)$ are dependent by the logic of the answer to **37**. Then, if we move back to $\mathbb{R}^n$ wouldn't that imply that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are dependent by the logic of the answer to **36**? I am clearly missing something, any insight would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to question $36$ is correct.

For the question $37$, your justification is neither clear nor correct: "if n < p and m < p then the T(v1),...,T(vm) will have p-m more vectors then a basis in space P and as such may not necessarily be independent". You're saying that if you have a family of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^p$ which cardinality is less than $p$ then it might not be independent, i.e, it can be dependent as it can be independent. It seems to me you just said a tautology: if $P$ is a proposition then we have $Q$ or $\lnot{Q}$. It's like someone saying "if the cardinality of a family of vectors in a finite dimensional space is greater than $\dim{E}$ then this family may not be independent". This statement gave us no information (in fact this family MUST be dependent). So in your case you have to PROVE that we can have both by giving examples. Otherwise, without comparing the numbers $n$, $m$ and $p$, you can actually prove easly that what's in $37$ is incorrect: simply take easy examples like the null map.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you prove that the statement in 37 is incorrect.

Comment: is there a proof I can write @Scientifica

Comment: I didn't give you a proof to $37$, but explained how you can solve it and give you a hint about how to disprove $37$ using a counter-example: suppose $T=0$. Then what are $T(v_1),T(v_2),\cdots,T(v_m)$

Comment: I am not sure I totally follow, but so far what I have is:
v1...vm are independent 
T[v1....vm] = 0 
T[v1] +....T[vm] = 0
Then it is possible that -T[vm] = T[v1]...T[vm-1] ? I am unsure. @Scientifica

Comment: @ANB What do you mean by T[v1...vm]=0 ? Never mind, since $\forall i\in\{1,\cdots ,m\},\,T(v_i)=0$ then yes you have $T(v_1)+\cdots +T(v_m)=0$ and this is enaugh to say that $(T(v_i))_{i\in\{1,\cdots ,m\}}$ is linearly dependent (check the definition of a linearly independent family). But you don't need to do that; simply use the fact that every linearly independent family doesn't contain any $0$ vector (thus by contraposition any family that contains a $0$ vector is linearly dependent).

Comment: T(v1)+⋯+T(vm)= 0 is enough to say that these vectors are linearly dependent? @Scientifica

Comment: @BNA What's the definition of linearly independent vectors?

Comment: if the solution to the equation c1V1+...+cmVm = 0 is the trivial solution c1=...=cm = 0, they are independent. But do we know from T(v1)+⋯+T(vm)= 0 that this implies there is a non-trivial solution?

Comment: Of course! The vectors $v_1,\cdots ,v_m$ are linearly independent if and only if $\forall c_1,\cdots ,c_m,\in F,\,\sum_{i=1}c_iv_i=0\implies \forall i\in\{1,\cdots ,m\},\,c_i=0$ where $F$ is a field (can be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). Now what is the negation of this, the negation being the definition of linearly dependent vectors.

Comment: Thanks so much! @Scientifica

Comment: @BNA No problem. I'm glad that you understood. One remark: as you understood,since $T(v_1)+\cdots +T(v_m)=0$ then $(T(v_i))_{i\in\{1,\cdots ,m\}}$ is linearly dependent. However, saying that $T(v_1)=0$ is enough. In fact, the following proposition holds: (try to prove it) Let $(u_i)_{i\in\{1,\cdots ,n\}}$ be a family of vectors. If $\exists p\in\{1,\cdots ,n\},\,u_p=0$ then that family is linearly dependent.